# Problems implementing ToString specialization for unit testing c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing

Right now i'm busy writing an event based queue. I wanted to do some unit testing but i'm running into an error. In Microsoft Visual Studio, when making a unit test project, you have to implement this function for each type you do an assert on:

```
namespace Microsoft
{
    namespace VisualStudio
    {
        namespace CppUnitTestFramework
        {
            template<> static std::wstring ToString<T>>(const class T& t)
            {
                //code goes here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is that the queue is not changing the object that was passed into it. because of this i wanted to write a unit test that verified that the object pointed to in the queue, was the same address as the object outside of the queue. I wrote the test as follows:

```
TEST_METHOD(REGISTERED_PROCESSORS_HAVE_ACCURATE_ADDRESSES_IN_QUEUE_MANAGER)
{
    QueueProcessor queue;
    ActionProcessor processor;

    processor.loadFromJson({ {actionProcessorProperties::QUEUE_NAME, "alpha"} });
    
    queue.registerProcessor(&processor);

    Assert::AreEqual(&processor, queue.processors["alpha"][0]);
}
```

i then get this error:

```
Test writer must define specialization of ToString<Q* q> for your class class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > __cdecl Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework::ToString<class ActionProcessor>(class ActionProcessor *).
```

so how do I implement `ToString` on a pointer? when I try putting the data type in the compiler complains. Also how do I then display the pointer as a string value?

thanks for the help.

#### edit:

i found the unit test works fine if you convert the pointers to uintptr_t. However the type conversion mid assert kinda messes up the readability of the code. Is there a cleaner solution?

```
TEST_METHOD(REGISTERED_PROCESSORS_HAVE_ACCURATE_ADDRESSES_IN_QUEUE_MANAGER)
{
    QueueProcessor queue;
    ActionProcessor processor;

    processor.loadFromJson({ {actionProcessorProperties::QUEUE_NAME, "alpha"} });
    
    queue.registerProcessor(&processor);

    Assert::AreEqual(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t> (&processor),
                     reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(queue.processors["alpha"][0]));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody seems to be answering this, I'm going to mark my edit as correct. Perhaps the way to do it is by converting the pointers to uintptr_t types. The code below fixes the issue:

```
TEST_METHOD(REGISTERED_PROCESSORS_HAVE_ACCURATE_ADDRESSES_IN_QUEUE_MANAGER)
{
    QueueProcessor queue;
    ActionProcessor processor;

    processor.loadFromJson({ {actionProcessorProperties::QUEUE_NAME, "alpha"} });

    queue.registerProcessor(&processor);

    Assert::AreEqual(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t> (&processor),
                     reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(queue.processors["alpha"][0]));
}
```